# Multi Shaders for Same Material

Tags: texturing, shaders

I have an ashtray model(picture1). I picked some faces(picture 2) and applied an material for ash and some part of metal under it. i mixed two textures with MixRGB node and used black/white image as alpha to clean around ash so that the metal part seems. But in the end, i want my ash part not glossy(diffuse) and metal part glossy. How can i achieve it ?

Picture 1 - My mesh

[image]

Picture 2 - The Faces i applied my ash/metal metarial

[image]

Picture 3- Node setup i used to mix metal and ash texture with help of an alpha image

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: just to clarify, you have two separate materials or one material for both the metal and ash parts?

Comment: It is one material with for both. I wanted to use different shader for each ash and metal part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of one shader (Glossy), use a Mix shader node that is fed by the Glossy node and a Diffuse node, and plug that alpha image into the mix factor of the mix shader to control where the shader type is.

Comment: i tried it that way plus adding transparent node instead of mixRGB and it worked! thank you. Here is the new node setup. https://prnt.sc/hg1rm6

Comment: Hey Craig, can i use different UV Maps for each shader ? Is it possible ?

Comment: As long as you name each uv map differently and call it in the uv coordinate node, yes.

Comment: when i export my mesh as collada, which uvmap does it set for that face ? Because i will bake textures for my mesh.

Comment: If you are exporting the whole project, I am not sure of how you want it to be set up as final- I normally bake to get one main uv map that takes all the other uv maps out of the equation, giving me a way to stencil between shaders with just one mask, but still use the same mapping for other things like glossy, etc.